# AWS SMS: How to get Delivery Status via direct SNS Notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm able to send SMS' fine through AWS SNS. I've also setup CloudWatch, and can see the logs for sent SMS'. However, I cannot find a way to subscribe a SNS topic to the delivery event? So as soon as the SMS has resulted in a successful or failed delivery over the network, I will get a HTTPS post to a url to log the result. This is easily setup in SES, for something like bounces, but I can't find anything obvious on the SNS dashboard, and trying to setup notifications on CloudWatch seems counter-intuitive since we shouldn't need to leave the SNS environment. What am I missing here?

Just to add: The notification needs to happen immediately on delivery status (CloudWatch seems delayed). For some reason AWS does not immediately fail on an obviously fake number (and happily makes you pay the full price of a SMS), and so need the resultant failure ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Hi The only way I know to track the delivery status for SMS sending is do a logsubscription to a aws lambda or kinesis stream. So the recipe would be:

- Create role to let SNS write logs (success and failures) into cloudwatch. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html#sms_stats_cloudwatch_metrics
- Create kinesis stream
- Do logsubscription for the logGroups. this implies create a role as well http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#DestinationKinesisExample

Finally have in mind that logs written in cloudwatch are compressed in gzip format and encoded in base64 so to be able to read the logs properly you would need to decompress and decode the data once you have red it from the kinesis stream